# How do I have a binary package for each supported architecture in Nuget?

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a native library (`.dll`, `.so`, `.dylib`) that I want to publish to Nuget. The shared library is about 80mb in size, so I want to publish a separate Nuget package for each supported RID. Consumers should only pay the size penalty for platforms that they need.

What is unclear is how to actually accomplish this.

```
Foo package (.NET binding code only, requires exactly one native package)
├── Foo linux-x64 native package
└── Foo osx.12-arm64 native package
```

- Do I need to follow a naming convention for the native package names (e.g. `Foo.native.linux-x64`)?
- Where do I put the native shared library in each native package?
- Do I need to add any information to my project file so that it points to the various native packages?

I am using .NET 6.0 (LTS)

Comment: preview docs: https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/pull/3092